# Django admin page not found

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-settings

Basically, I've been following the tutorial but I am stuck when it comes to getting the admin page to work.

The error I get is: The requested URL /admin/ was not found on this server.
So I looked at lots of forums and quite a few stackoverflow question but since I am a complete newbie so I don't understand half of them and the other half's solution doesn't solve my problem.

This is what my settings.py looks like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'polls'
)
```

This is what my urls.py looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url


# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'BoE.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^BoE/', include('BoE.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: That error doesn't sound like a Django error. Are you using the `runserver` development server, or a real webserver like Apache? If it's the latter, you most likely don't have the wsgi connection between your Django instance and Apache or whatever set up properly. In general, if you're in development, a full webserver is just a headache, and I'd be wary of any tutorial that starts you off that way.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am using the runserver development server as suggested by the tutorial

Comment: is it django yellow page error

Comment: If you're using `runserver` and a 404 is raised, your error should be accompanied by a stacktrace (all the stuff below the error). If you have that, post it. If you're not seeing a stacktrace then make sure you have `DEBUG=True` in your settings.

Comment: What did you type before ``/admin/``?

Comment: can you put what you are getting in stacktrace here...

Comment: @Paritosh Hi Paritosh, no its a white page. and i am not sure how to access the stacktrace :/

Comment: @ChrisPratt this is really odd, i do have DEBUG=True but still no stacktrace

Comment: @Izzad-DinRuhulessin before admin I typed my elastic IP

Comment: I am not sure how relavent this is but the server I am running is an AWS Bitnami EC2 instance, so when I get to the webpage I get a welcome from bitnami.

Comment: http://54.247.125.185/
this is the website

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you get the "Welcome to Django" page when you when to  http:// 127 0 0 1:8000? (with dots)

Are you going to http:// 127 0 0 1:8000/admin/ ?

Did everything from tutorial part one work? Did you see the items in the database?

---

In the below comments, we figured that the problem was not with Django, as he had the exact same code that I had (and mine worked). He had to go to wiki.bitnami.org/Components/Django and follow the instructions there

Comment: I got welcome to Django but not on 127.... I got it on the elastic IP that I assigned to my server.
My server is a Bitnami DjangoStack EC2 instance.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on this page: http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/Django ? I recently did the polls tutorial, and your code snippets are identical to mine, so the problem is this Bitnani-Django relationship

Comment: Could you select my answer as the correct one then? It's a little arrow that appears on the left side; you click it and I get a check mark :)

Comment: :) sorry, i originally wanted to do it but didn't know how to. You should have a check mark now. Thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: if you have some time, could you please help me here :D  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659126/bitnami-django-creating-multiple-projects

Comment: Hey, Amir. I looked around but I couldn't find anything that can help with that question. I've never received it (Django gives 'Page not found' and then some code and information about the URLs, but never 'Not Found'. I assume it's something about bitnami again :(

Comment: but do multiple projects work for you? I might just try create another machine from start.

Comment: I don't do multiple projects yet? I just started my first programming job 2 months ago =(. Sorry

Comment: Oh, and by the way, if you figure out the answer to your question, post it and I'll vote you up - you get more privileges the more points you have :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and take a stab, because this is the only thing I can think of that could still be the issue.

If you run just `python manage.py runserver` the dev server binds to 127.0.0.1:8000. However, unless you're running in a browser that is literally on the machine, or otherwise accessing it through the machine directly (X Window, VNC, tunnel, etc), you can't access this remotely.

If you want to access the dev server at the actual IP address, you need to tell it to bind to the primary interface:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then, you'll be able to access your the site in your local browser with `http://<ip>:8000/admin/`

Comment: I did run it with 0.0.0.0:8000 but nothing. I even, just now, made a new server from scratch.
I begining to think if its something to do with how Bitnami handles things.