# Bitnami Django creating multiple projects

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, project, bitnami

So I have this Bitnami EC2 instance which had project 'Project' in it by default (at /apps/django/django_projects), so I started following the django tutorial and done everything. I am able to access this project at

```
http://myIp/Project/.
```

So after having finished the tutorial I set off to create my own project. I created the project using

```
django-admin.py startproject DoE
```

in the same directory as project 'Project' (i.e. /apps/django/django_projects), followed by

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But the problem is when I go to

```
http://myIp/DoE/
```

I get this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /DoE/ was not found on this server.
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a way to work around this issue, it's a bit hacky but it does the job.
I got it from here http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/Django.
But they imply that you only need to do this if you are using an apache webserver which I am not. I am using the django's development server, but nevertheless it works.

Basically I had to create a DoE.conf file in /home/bitnami/apps/django/conf which looks like this:

```
Alias /static "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static"

<Directory '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib'>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /DoE "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/scripts/DoE.wsgi"

<Directory '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/scripts'>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and then create a file named DoE.wsgi in /home/bitnami/apps/django/scripts which looks like this:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects')
sys.path.append('/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/DoE')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'DoE.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

after that I had to include

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/django/conf/DoE.conf
```

in my httpd.conf file, which for my case was here: /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf

After this I restarted my machine/server and all was well :)

Comment: Cool! Now select your answer as 'the answer' :)

Comment: @Dana thank you very much for helping with with stackoverflow and bitnami :)

Comment: this is cool but tell me how to link a domain/subdomain directly to a django project? right now the domain point to bitnami welcome page, i want my webapp to be served on domain directly