# Django admin panel new action intermediate page

Tags: django

I added to admin panel new action with redirection to intermediate page. But my problem is that I don't know where to put the template of intermediate page. No matter where I put it, I get 404 error. So my question is where should I put the template of my intermediate page. (what should be it's exactly path)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django admin page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582867/django-admin-page-not-found)

Comment: Did you try with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582867/django-admin-page-not-found